# Authorize uid in firebase realtime database rules using rest api

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

let say i have these rules in realtime DB

```
  "rules": {
       ".read": "auth !== null",
       ".write": "true"
    }
```

and i'm using axios to read data

`` axios.get(`https://DBNAME.firebaseio.com/user.json?auth=${token}`) ``
it's working fine
but when i have these Rules

```
"rules": {
    "$uid":{
       ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth !== null"
        }
  }
```

and then again reading from that get request it return 401 error code (unauthorized) 
So how can i authenticate the rules including uid etc using rest api 
like 
placing a uid in the place of token or something else

```
axios.get(`https://DBNAME.firebaseio.com/user.json?auth=${uid}`)
```

Pleas guide me the right way of doing so

Thank You